# Very simple 15 lines of programing

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y;
    cin>> y;

    if (y = 9);
    {
     cout<< "notgood";
     }


    cout<< "good";
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't get it too cout just "good" by itself. do I need a else and if I need a else wont that mean I would need to rewrite system pause and return 0? I know its simples but can somone give me some help on what I must do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (y == 9) {
  cout << "notgood";
 }
```

`=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. And the `;` immediately after the `if` was terminating the statement.

You need to bone up on your basic syntax, SO is not a tutoring service.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the operator = is assignment and if you want to compare two values you must use ==, so the if should be `if (y == 9)` and also you don't want the semicolon right after the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to avoid making the mistake others have already pointed out, you can switch the places of the two operands, e.g.:

```
if (9 == y)...
```

This way, if you accidentally mistake the `==` operator for the `=` operator, you will get an error for trying to assign no a non lvalue.

Comment: These days, I think most prefer to use the most natural syntax y==9 and let compiler warnings do their job. Some even consider it code smell to us unnatural syntax like 9==y because it may indicate coder does not care about compiler warnings.

Comment: This is the case with me, I've never used that approach myself, but still, it may be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use  == `(y == 9)`

a single = means assignment

Answer (score 1):

You'll get both out as written.  Try it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int y;
    cin>> y;
    if (y == 9) {
        cout<< "notgood";
    } else {
        cout<< "good";
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Don't know what the number 9 did to be considered "not good"...

If you're learning, start thinking about developing a consistent style for brace placement, use of whitespace, etc.  It'll make your code easier to read, understand, and debug.  Randomness makes you look sloppy and your code harder to understand.

Comment: and btw 9 isnt good because it was eaten by 7 budum tsss

Comment: Funnier if you write "ate by seven"...